# Angular with SWIG middleware

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, swig-template

I have small problems with using `{{}}` on both sides. For example `{{}}` in content of tag i could change to `ng-bind-html="Content"` but for example when i have `ng-src` attribute and i need to load data from variable how i would success that?
If there any middleware like SWIG, just with for example `{{{}}}` use or something like that? Middleware i need it html like middle ware.
Perhaps SWIG could change `{{}}` to something else and work with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change either SWIG or Angular to use something else - here's an example of changing SWIG and an article.

```
swig.setDefaults({ varControls: ['<%=', '%>'] });
```

https://thesagaciouscoder.wordpress.com/2014/09/02/making-swig-and-angular-play-along/